# Set user info with cookie-session

Tags: node.js, session, cookie-session

I'm using cookie-session to store all my session information.
After my users login, I store his information inside req.session.user like this

```
req.session.user = _.omit(client.dataValues, [
     "password",
     "createdAt",
     "updatedAt"
]);
```

Using console.log I can see that everything is setted ok, but when I try to use req.session.user in another route, I get undefined.
My cookie is setted like this

```
app.use(
  cookiesession({
    name: "name",
    keys: ["key1", "key2"],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: false,
    options: {
      secure: false,
      secret: "secrete",
      overwrite: true
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: where is your console.log ? It must be in a handler after the `cookiesession` middleware

Comment: After I add req.session.user in the login router